# Matlab - Error using imwrite

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I have a weird problem... I want to create a video with the extension .tif with a lot  of frames. My script is running well 2 times over 3 but it crashes randomly sometimes...

I have a loop which has the length of the total of frames in the video and at each turn I add a tif to my multipage tif.

There is my code to create the new video :

```
% --- Create the new frame
newVid.cData = iL(y0:y0end, x0:x0end);

% --- Create the new video
if nbrFrames == 1
    imwrite(newVid.cData,dataOutVid);
else
    imwrite(newVid.cData,dataOutVid,'WriteMode','append');
end
```

Each turn I change the value of "newVid.cData". in fact the new video is a portion of an original video in which I focused on a specific object (a mouse for me). "dataOutVid" is the path where I store the new video and the extension of the path is .tif.

How I obtain the path:

```
disp('Where do you want to save the new video and under which name ?');
[name, path] = uiputfile({'.tif'}, 'Save Video');
dataOutVid = strcat(path,name);
```

There is the mistake I can possibly have randomly:

```
Error using imwrite (line 454)
Unable to open file "D:\Matlab\Traitement Vidéo\test.tif" for writing. You might not have write permission.

Error in mouseExtraction(line 164)
imwrite(newVid.cData,dataOutVid,'WriteMode','append');
```

Well I don't understand why this error appears randomly (one time at the frame 270, another time at the frame 1250, etc...). How is it possible I suddendly loose the right to overwrite my file...

Edit : I already checked if I didn't have a RAM problem but I only use 20% of it during the execution of the script...

Comment: Random write and read errors like that (in my experience) may mean that one (or more) of your RAM modules are about to fail.  I suggest using a memory diagnostic tool such as [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) to make sure that this is the case.

Comment: I forgot to mention that... I will edit my post but I don't have a problem with my RAM modules. In fact I only use 20% of my RAM. I already checked that point.

Comment: How **exactly** did you check? Using 20% of your RAM doesn't mean anything if that portion of the 20% is the affected part of your RAM that is failing.  My gut feeling still says to use memtest and check your RAM.  Random read/write errors are usually a symptom of defective RAM... especially if the frames that are failing to write are random and not deterministic.

Comment: I checked using the task manager

Comment: Task manager is **not** enough.  Use a dedicated RAM diagnostic tool to help you determine RAM errors.  Also, try your script on **another** computer and see if there are any failures like you're experiencing.

Comment: And if it's a memory problem. How could I solve my problem ? Thank you, I'll try to use memtest

Comment: @AntoineMaugein Replace the faulty stick of RAM.

Comment: Using memtest, test one RAM module at a time to isolate out the affected modules.  If and when you finally determine which RAM modules are affected, you have two options: (1) Pull out the affected modules and work with decreased memory or (2) Buy new RAM.  Because you're working with video, option 1 may not be a viable one as storing large amounts of video frames in memory are going to need all of the RAM you can get. This leaves you with option 2 and there's unfortunately no other way around the issue :)... and please don't go here: http://downloadmoreram.com/

Comment: Thank you ! 
hahaha I will not I am not that stupid ! Just a newbie of matlab...